# How well does the Tokina AT-X 16-28 F2.8 resist flare?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, lens-flare, tokina

Nowadays (among other projects) I'm shooting candle lights in churches (using mostly long exposures) using a Canon 17-40mm F4. (A small part of) The results are [here](http://vatopaidi.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/spod33/).

I'm thinking now to buy a Tokina AT-X 16-28 F2.8 mostly because it gives me:

- One stop faster
- Much lower distortion

...but I'm concerned on how much the Tokina lens are flare resistant in the above situations (shooting candles & other light sources in a dark environment - see the link) and will not give me different green 'aliens', ghosting or any other artifacts in a much more percentage compared with Canon 17-40 F4. Perhaps I should note that I use a Canon FF camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this lens a lot, but I have not taken any pictures by candlelight.  I have done long exposure photography in the vicinity of streetlights with no flare issues.  I do know that you have to be very careful about flare in sunlight.